# generating js code from python, not sure if going the right path

Tags: javascript, python, html, w2ui

I have a web application that is structured as the following:

Server is written in Python. It serves the client an HTML page with
about 100 different tables (grids) and matching JS files. Every grid is a DIV with JS code that initializes it:

page.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/assets/js/grid_type_1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/assets/js/grid_type_2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/assets/js/grid_type_3.js"></script>

<div id="grid_type_1" style="width: 100%; height: 200px;"></div>
<div id="grid_type_2" style="width: 100%; height: 200px;"></div>
<div id="grid_type_3" style="width: 100%; height: 200px;"></div>
```

grid_type_1.js:

```
$(function () {
    w2utils.settings['dataType'] = 'JSON'  
    $('#grid_type_1').w2grid({
       // configuration here
});
```

All the JS files use the same UI framework (W2UI) but each grid is of different configuration and structure. After the page loads, each grid makes a POST request to the server and it replies with a JSON that is used to populate that grid with entries.

I'm already using Jinja2 to template the HTML files and 80% of the code in the JS files is the same, so I was thinking if it would be better to generate the JS files as well, instead of duplicating 80% of the JS grid code 100 times.

Is it a viable approach to this issue?